# date comparison error when using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

using openpyxl
I am getting the error argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
print(row[date_submitted_index]) gives output of 2023-02-07 00:00:00
when it hits the line if date_submitted  >= today_as_datetime it gives the error:argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
ws = wb.active
# Get the values from the worksheet as a list of lists
data = [row for row in ws.values]
# Get the headers from the first row of the data
headers = data[0]
date_submitted_index = headers.index("Date Submitted")

for i, row in enumerate(data[1:], start=1):
    if "Submitted" in row[complete_index]:
       print(row[date_submitted_index])#outputs 2023-02-07 00:00:00
       print(type(row[date_submitted_index])) #outputs <class 'datetime.datetime'>
       date_submitted = row[date_submitted_index]
       if date_submitted is not None:
         today_as_datetime = datetime.today()
         # Check if the value in the date submitted is today's date or after date
        if date_submitted  <= today_as_datetime: #gives error argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
            #do some things
```

Comment: What is row? We have to assume that 'date_submitted' cannot be compared with a datetime value. Is there any more to the error other than just 'argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable'?

Comment: It is what I'm using to check the values of the row and date submitted is the index of the column. It outputs  2023-02-07 00:00:00 in this row. The none is what I get when I try to compare it with datetime.today(). If  convert it to match the format of the value in the column's output. The format becomes a string while the columns value is a date. It then will error saying  can't compare a string with a date object

Comment: I should have been more specific, what type is 'row' , what is the code that generates it? A string date can be compared with a date (converted if necessary). If you are reading a date value from an Excel cell it should be datetime.

Comment: The exception doesn't match the code. Please provide full details for a reproducible example.

Comment: updated the code example to provide more context upstream.

Comment: print(type(row[date_submitted_index])) #outputs <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: @moken If I convert the excel value to a string and  use todays date as string and do a string comparison it will work, but from what I read it is not recommended to do dates comparison via strings